# Swift class subclassed from Objective-C lightweight generic class not visible from Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics, language-interoperability

I have an objective-c class

```
@interface LightweightGenericHolder<T: NSObject*> : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) T value;

@end
```

I created swift subclass from it

```
public class LightweightGenericHolderSubclass: LightweightGenericHolder<NSString> {

}
```

Usage of **LightweightGenericHolderSubclass** in objective-c code produces an error **Use of undeclared identifier 'LightweightGenericHolderSubclass'**

How can i make this class visible?

Thanks.

Comment: At a minimum, to be visible to ObjC, you need to add `@objc` to the class definition. (I haven't double-checked whether this will fix the entire problem, but it's required since the removal of objc-inference.)

Comment: @RobNapier adding _@objc_ flag produces an error **Generic subclasses of '@objc' classes cannot have an explicit '@objc' because they are not directly visible from Objective-C. Replace '@objc ' with ''**

Comment: I would say that's your answer. "Generic subclasses of @objc classes are not directly visible from Objective-C." You can't do this.

Comment: May be there is some workaround?

Comment: Sure; make a Swift class that is not a subclass of LightweightGenericHolder, and then write a ObjC subclass of LightweightGenericHolder that calls it. (Or just write the entire subclass in ObjC.) But the Swift type can't make use of any `LightweightGenericHolder` code (since it's not a subclass). There is no workaround that looks like "and then my Swift subclass is visible in ObjC." If there were, the compiler would just do that.

Comment: Okey, I got it. Thank you!